# Pyramid and Chameleon ZPT Repetition

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

I am trying to loop through a list and get an output like this:

Python:

```
items=['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
return dict(items=items)
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/item1>item1</a></li>
<li><a href="/item1>item2</a></li>
<li><a href="/item1>item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can get the list part right but adding it to the anchor is not going so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about (supposing 'items' is a namespace passed from your code to your template):

```
<ul>
 <tal:block repeat="item items">
  <li><a href="" tal:attributes="href item" tal:content="item">item</a></li>
 </tal:block>
</ul>
```

You can put tal:repeat on the li element, but I personally like to use a dedicated tag using an element in the tal namespace (idiomatic choice is tal:block).

Also see: http://drdobbs.com/web-development/184404974

Comment: Thank you so much, works almost perfectly.
One Problem though. you have to <li href...> does not work.
You have to add <a></a> with the href and tal:attributes.

One more bonus question. Is it possible to concatenate href to make it href="/file/item1". Thanks again.

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Yeah, I saw the HTML flub and corrected in answer above.

Comment: for /file/item1 use tal:attributes="href string:/file/${item}" as your expression.

Comment: Great! Worked as well. Thanks again!

Comment: You can use ${...} expressions to simplify this. Your li would then become <li><a href="${item}">${item}</a></li>, which is a bit easier to read.